# Sum-aggregation script for term frequencies without dynamic scripting

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I try to evaluate a web-application for my masterthesis. For this I want to make a user study, where I prepare the data in elasitc found, and send my web application to the testers. As far as I know, elastic found does not allow dynamic scripting for security reasons. I try to refomulate the following dynamic script query:

```
GET my_index/document/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all":{}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "stadt": {
      "sum": {
        "script": "_index['textBody']['frankfurt'].tf()"
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

This query sums up all term frequencies in the document field `textBody` for the term `frankfurt`.

In order to reformulate the query without dynamic scripting, I've taken a look on [groovy scripts without dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/blog/running-groovy-scripts-without-dynamic-scripting), but I still get parsing errors.

My approach to this was:

```
GET my_index/document/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all":{}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "stadt": {
      "sum": {
        "script": {
            "script_id": "termFrequency",
            "lang" : "groovy",
            "params": {
              "term" : "frankfurt"
            }
        }        
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

and the file `termFrequency.groovy` in the `scripts` directory:

```
_index['textBody'][term].tf()
```

I get the following parsing error:

```
Parse Failure [Unexpected token START_OBJECT in [stadt].]
```

Comment: What version of ES you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct syntax assuming your file is inside `config/scripts` directory.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "stadt": {
      "sum": {
        "script_file": "termFrequency",
        "lang": "groovy",
        "params": {
          "term": "frankfurt"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Also the **term** should be `variable` rather than `string` so it should be

```
_index['textBody'][term].tf()
```

Hope this helps!